# PHP function scope

Tags: php

I know this is kind of a hacky thing I'm trying here, but I'm wondering if this is even possible. is there anyway I can access the `$x` variable in the following code, without passing arguments?

```
function foo() {
 $x = 1;
 return bar();
}

function bar() {
  //get $x from foo here somehow?
  return $x ? 'stuff' : 'other stuff';
}
```

Comment: With regards to the date the questions were asked, I'd actually consider the *other* question as a duplicate of this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure why, but you can use globals that opens up to a whole thing, but i will show you:

```
function foo() {
 global $x;
 $x = 1;
 return bar();
}

function bar() {
  global $x;
  //get $x from foo here somehow?
  return $x ? 'stuff' : 'other stuff';
}
```

Here is the demo: http://codepad.org/fPqUXzyC

It is always better to not use globals and just pass parameters, but if you cannot you could use globals

Comment: I agree, the code ends up becoming a lot less manageable and more prone to lots of dependency issues if you are using variables in the global scope without ... scoping them somehow within objects or something similar.

Comment: I suspect the OP knows how to use globals but is looking for an `uplevel` type of functionality.

Comment: @webbiedave, what does that mean? and don't `suspect` anything, how do you know?

Comment: The reason this "works" is because PHP creates variables if they don't already exist. The `global` statement creates `$x` in the global scope.

Comment: @Neal: I don't know. I only suspect it because he is already a programmer in multiple languages, takes computer science classes and stated he was trying to do something "hacky". Also, check out his answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909647/make-all-variables-global-php/1909663#1909663 and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067251/what-is-the-best-way-to-pass-or-access-other-objects-in-other-classes-in-php/2067266#2067266

Comment: @webbiedave, i have no idea :-p

Comment: @Neal: I borrowed `uplevel` from TCL which allows access to variables up the stack. PHP has no equivalent capability.

Comment: you might update you answer .. suggesting people to use `global` is a really bad thing

Answer (score 4):

```
class baz {
   private $x;
   public function foo() {
      $this->x = 1;
      return $this->bar();
   }

   public function bar() {
      return $this->x ? 'stuff' : 'other stuff';
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could make `foo()` store the `$x` value to [`$GLOBALS[]`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php) or [`global $x;`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). Other than that, nothing I can think of would do it. It would need to be purposely exposed to get it from inside another function.

If this is your code, I may recommend thinking about taking an object-oriented approach.

```
class Foo
{
  public static $x;

  public static function Foo(){
    Foo::$x = 1;
    return Foo::Bar();
  }

  public static function Bar() {
    return Foo::$x ? 'stuff' : 'other stuff';
  }
}

echo Foo::Foo();
```

Alternatively, do as others have suggested and pass `$x` as a function parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is kind of old, and an answer has already been accepted, but wouldn't this work?

```
function foo() 
  {  
    $x = 1;  
    return bar($x); 
  }  

function bar($x) 
  {
    return $x ? 'stuff' : 'other stuff'; 
  }
```

Comment: as I said in the question, it had to be without accepting agruments, as I couldn't change the signature of the `bar()` function. so no, this would not work in this scenario.

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked that part. Do I understand correctly that you cannot edit bar() at all? If you could, then you might use func_get_args to allow you to pass in another value.